# php mysql UPDATE multiple fields in one record at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to UPDATE every field (16 fields plus the key) in a record in a MySQL database with some new data from a form using php.  It works fine with INSERT but when I try to change to UPDATE it won't do it.  I also feel this is a very long way to do it and there is probably a more iterative solution, I would really appreciate some help please:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$con=mysqli_connect($hh,$un,$pw,$db);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
echo 'Connected successfully';

$sql = "UPDATE PiBQ_Config 
        SET (upButton, dnButton, stepCore1, stepCore2, stepCore3, stepCore4, limSwitch, waitTime, maxPosn, pidKp, pidKi, pidKd, intMax, intMin, sleepTime, progRun) =
        ('$_POST[upButton]', '$_POST[dnButton]', '$_POST[stepCore1]', '$_POST[stepCore2]', '$_POST[stepCore3]', '$_POST[stepCore4]', '$_POST[limSwitch]', '$_POST[waitTime]', '$_POST[maxPosn]', '$_POST[pidKp]', '$_POST[pidKi]', '$_POST[pidKd]', '$_POST[intMax]', '$_POST[intMin]', '$_POST[sleepTime]', '$_POST[progRun]')
        WHERE tableKey = 1";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "1 record added";
header ('location: ../settings.php');

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: change your "=" sign to "VALUES"

Comment: Note that even if this worked, you should _not_ construct your queries this way. Please look into [prepared statements and bound parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

Set each field individually for example:

```
"UPDATE PiBQ_Config 
        SET upButton = '$_POST[upButton]',
       dnButton ='$_POST[upButton]', 
      stepCore1 = '$_POST[dnButton]', 
    .
    . 
    .//the rest of variables
    WHERE tableKey = 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This method creates a query from three parameters: the table name, an associative array which has the name of the columns as keys and another whitch has the name of the column you want to update as keys for the where statement.

```
public function update($table, $data, $where)
{
    $query='UPDATE `'.$table.'` SET ';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= '`'.$key.'`=:'.$key.','; 
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    $query .= ' WHERE ';
    foreach($where as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= '`'.$key.'`=:'.$key.','; 
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);

    $data += $where;

    $update = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $update->execute($data);
}
```

It will build a query and execute it. You should use PDO and prepared statements for more security.

**Example:**

for example you want to update the name of a user in the database.

```
$firstName = 'newFirstName';
$lastName = 'newLastName';
$id = idOfUserYouWantToUpdate;

$table = 'users';
$data = array('user_firstname'=>$firstName, 'user_lastname'=>$lastName);
$where = array('user_id'=>$id)

update($table, $data, $where);
```